# android Webview is consuming whole layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, webview

in my project i have a following layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/textview"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:id="@+id/textview"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/border">
            </WebView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/textview2"
                android:textSize="28sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

so i have three(3) sublayout inside main FrameLayout

```
-FrameLayout
   -LinearLayout
       -İmageButton(1)
       -Textview(1)
       -İmageButton(2)
   -LinearLayout
       -Webview
   -LinearLAyout
       -textview(2)
```

but unfortunatly android renders the layout wrongly

main and only problem is: textview(2) hasnt been showed in screen

here is the screenshot of the page:

[image: buggy layout]

```
1 ---> button
2 ---> textview(1)
3 ---> button2
4 ---> webview
5 ---> textview(2) //XXX main point
```

but i want something like the following:

[image: layout]

how can i do that?

what modifications do i need to do?

thanx in advance

Comment: don't use fill_parent for the height of the parent linear layout, instead, use weights: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

Comment: So should i change layout.height to layout.weight=1 or 0? And Linearlayout of webview right?

Comment: use match parent and set webview above your 5th no layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use weight property instead of fill parent

Use below code, I have made changes

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/blackColor"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/textview"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:id="@+id/textview"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/blackColor"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/border">
        </WebView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/textview2"
            android:textSize="28sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

You can play with `android:layout_weight="0.1"` property and make suitable changes.